# RACSubject and disposal

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I am trying to create a signal that will cancel a `NSURLSessionDataTask` upon disposal. The problem is that I am not able to wait for the task to finish until I can send next values (implementing [Server-sent Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events)), but I have to use the `NSURLSession`s delegate methods.

What I am doing right now is creating a `RACSubject` and returning it for every new request. Upon new events arrive, I `sendNext:` on the subject. The problem I have is figuring out when to efficiently cancel the task, if there are no more subscribers on the subject.

A workaround I found so far is creating a dummy signal and merging it with the subject (see below).

```
return [[RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id <RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
        if ( dataTask.state != NSURLSessionTaskStateCanceling && dataTask.state != NSURLSessionTaskStateRunning ) {
            [dataTask cancel];
        }
    }];
}]
    merge:self.requests[@(dataTask.taskIdentifier)][kSubjectKey]];
```

But there has to be a more elegant way, or? Plus a downside is, that the signal will never complete. If I `sendCompleted` within the dummy signal, the dispose block will be called immediately.

I am using ReactiveCocoa 2.5.x

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this [library](https://github.com/travisjeffery/TRVSEventSource). Basically all you need is to turn the delegate methods into blocks and then you can use declare the blocks inside of `creatSignal:`call. Check out this [post](http://pivotallabs.com/wrapping-delegates-blocks/) if you want to wrap the delegate methods into blocks yourself.

Comment: That could be a workaround, yes. But I'm interested, if there is a way only using the framework to solve this problem.